# Error "only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" al usar ndarray en función

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, numpy

Tengo el siguiente código en Python, tengo problemas en la penúltima línea, no sé si al llamar al método `initial` hay un error.

¿Me pueden ayudar?

```
import numpy as np
from math import exp,ceil

def initial (x):
   init=0.09*exp(-x**2/50);
   return init

a = -20;
b= 20;
T=4;
M=500;
rhom=0.2;
n=10;
drho=rhom/n;
rho=np.linspace(0,rhom,n+1);#lim inf, lim sup, "step"`

def flux(rho):
    vf=15;
    rhomax=0.2;
    fl=vf*(1-rho/rhomax)*rho;
    return fl

frho=flux(rho)
qmax=max(frho);#Busca el máximo de la lista
s=np.argmax(frho)#devuelve el índice del valor máximo
rhostar=rho.item(s)#devuelve el elemento en la posición "i"
lamda=max(abs(frho[1:n]-frho[0:n-1]))/drho;
h=(b-a)/M;
ka=0.5*h/lamda;
N=ceil(T/ka);
k=T/N;
kio=np.insert(np.arange(a+h/2,b-h/2,h),len(np.arange(a+h/2,b-h/2,h)),b-h/2)# np.insert(lista,length,valor_a_agregar)
xticks=kio.transpose();
U=np.zeros((M,N+1));
U[:,1]=initial(xticks);
print(U[:,1])
```

Y me salió este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ALEX EDUARDO\Documents\HolaMundoPython.py", line 35, in <module>
    U[:,1]=initial(xticks);
  File "C:\Users\ALEX EDUARDO\Documents\HolaMundoPython.py", line 5, in initial
    init=0.09*exp(-x**2/50);
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: Hola Alex, el problema es que a `initial` le estas pasando un array y aplicas `math.exp` sobre el, cuando esta función espera  un solo escalar, no un array. Sería bueno que explicaras que pretendes conseguir con tu función `initial` para poder ayudarte. Un saludo.

Comment: Lo que quiero es que cada valor que está almacenado en xticks, se evalue en 0.09*exp(-x**2/50) y luego esos valores guardar en la primera columna de la matriz U

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se encuentra en la línea `init=0.09*exp(-x**2/50);` dado que `math.exp` de la biblioteca estándar espera unicamente un escalar como argumento, no está pensada para trabajar con arrays. NumPy suele proveer alternativas para hacer las mismas tareas sobre arrays, en este caso debes usar [`numpy.exp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.exp.html):

```
import numpy as np
from math import ceil


def initial(x):
    init = 0.09 * np.exp(-x**2/50)
    return init


a = -20
b = 20
T = 4
M = 500
rhom = 0.2
n = 10
drho = rhom / n
rho = np.linspace(0, rhom, n+1)  # lim inf, lim sup, "step"


def flux(rho):
    vf = 15
    rhomax = 0.2
    fl = vf * (1 - rho / rhomax) * rho
    return fl


frho = flux(rho)
qmax = max(frho)  # Busca el máximo de la lista
s = np.argmax(frho)  # Devuelve el índice del valor máximo
rhostar = rho.item(s)  # Devuelve el elemento en la posición "i"
lamda = max(abs(frho[1:n] - frho[0:n-1])) / drho
h = (b - a) / M
ka = 0.5 * h / lamda
N = ceil(T/ka)
k = T / N
kio = np.insert(np.arange(a+h/2, b-h/2, h), len(np.arange(a+h/2, b-h/2, h)), b-h/2)
xticks = kio.transpose()
U = np.zeros((M, N+1))
print(type(xticks))
U[:, 1] = initial(xticks)
print(U[:, 1])
```

> **Nota:** en Python no tienes que usar ; para delimitar cada instrucción (de hecho no se considera correcto por convención). Te recomiendo mirarte [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) para ver las guías de estilo del código.